# Ef Core - Problem with mapping tables "One To Many" relationship from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have two tables (`categories`, `subcategories`) in SQL Server and I try to map those tables for use in a webservice.

Table: **Categories**

```
id_category | category name        
------------+----------------
1             Technology
2             Sport
3             Furniture
```

Table: **Subcategories**

```
id_subcategory | subcategory_name | id_category
---------------+------------------+-------------
1                Smartphones        1
2                Smart_TV           1
3                Tablets            1
4                sport_gear         2
. 
. 
.
```

Using Entity Framework Core 3.1, I map those entities with two classes

```
[Table("categories", Schema = "Dbo")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id_category")]
    public int Id_category { get; set; }

    [Column("category name")]
    public string Name_category { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<SubCategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
}

[Table("subcategories", Schema = "Dbo")]
public class SubCategoria
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("id_subcategory")]
    public int Id_subcategory { get; set; }

    [Column("subcategory_name")]
    public string Name_subcat { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    [Column("id_category")]
    public int Id_cat { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `DbContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Subcategories)
            .WithOne(s => s.Category);
    }

    public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubCategory> subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is with when I want the Categories with their Subcategories

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
       return Ok(_context.categories.Include(x => x.Subcategories).ToList());
    }
```

I get this error message:

> Invalid column name 'CategoryId_category'
> Invalid column name 'CategoryId_category'
>
> System.Exception {Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Comment: Remove `[NotMapped]` attribute from `Category` property. If you have problems with JSON serialization, solve them with `[JsonIgnore]` or JSON serializer options rather than EF Core model data annotations.

Comment: Your column `category name` really has a space in it?

Comment: @IvanStoev or better; don't use db entities as frontend DTOs :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Doesnt works without [NotMapped] attribute. I got the same error message..

Comment: Remove both `[NotMapped]` attributes. You can also add `.HasForeignKey(s => s.Id_cat)` to the fluent configuration of the relationship, although `[ForeignKey("Category")]` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was on DataContext Configuration

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
         base.OnModelCreating(builder);

         builder.Entity<SubCategory>()
                .HasOne<Category>(s => s.Category)
                .WithMany(c => c.Subcategories)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.Id_cat);
    }
}
```